# how to add filterclass into applicationContext?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have a filterclass that i normally will put in web.xml.  may i know how to specify it inside spring applicationcontext so that i able to use spring features in my fitlerclass?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

leonm's answer is 100% correct, but like many things in Spring there are multiple ways of doing this (well at least in Spring Security's case).

You can also subclass `SpringSecurityFilter` and then add it to the Spring Security Filter Chain like this:

```
<bean id="mySecurityFilter" class="org.example.MySecurityFilter">
   ...setup like a normal bean
   <custom-filter position="LAST"/>
</bean>
```

Check out this link [`<security:custom-filter>`](http://spring.habuma.com/namespaces/spring-security-2.0/schemas/spring-security-2_0_xsd/elements/custom-filter.html) for all the different values you can use for the `position` argument.

Comment: if my filterclass is nothing to do with spring security. i add up this way as well? let say i want to add custom ntlmhttpfilter class that i normally add in web.xml

Comment: Probably not, but since I did not know what your filter was doing I figured I would show you the second option.

Answer (score 3):

Use a [DelegatingFilterProxy](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/2.0.x/reference/supporting-infrastructure.html#filters).